# GKE - Hybrid Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, high-availability, hybrid, on-premises-instances

I've been reading the Google Cloud documentation about **hybrid GKE cluster** with [Connect](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/registering-a-cluster) or completely on prem with GKE on-prem and VMWare.

However, I see that GKE with **Connect** you can manage the on-prem Kubernetes cluster from Google Cloud dashboard.

But, what I am trying to find, is, to mantain a hybrid cluster with GKE mixing **on-prem and cloud nodes**. Graphical example:

[image]

For the above solution, the master node is managed by GCloud, but the ideal solution is to manage **multiple node masters** (High availability) **on cloud** and nodes on prem. Graphical example:

[image]

Is it possible to apply some or both of the proposed solutions on Google Cloud with GKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain hybrid clusters, mixing on prem and cloud nodes, you need to use Anthos.

Anthos is a modern application management platform that provides a consistent development and operations experience for cloud and on-premises environments.

The primary computing environment for Anthos uses Anthos clusters, which extend GKE for use on Google Cloud, on-premises, or multicloud to manage Kubernetes installations in the environments where you intend to deploy your applications. These offerings bundle upstream Kubernetes releases and provide management capabilities for creating, scaling, and upgrading conformant Kubernetes clusters. With Kubernetes installed and running, you have access to a common orchestration layer that manages application deployment, configuration, upgrade, and scaling.

If you want to know more about Anthos in GCP please [follow this link.](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/overview)

Comment: But does it really support mixing on prem and cloud nodes within a single cluster?